# Array non-lvalue in assignment

Tags: c, arrays

```
int masivs[row][col],i,j,n,choice,r,c;

system("cls");
srand(time(NULL));
printf("Darba autors Einars Ozols\n");
printf("Sakummasive aizpilde \n");
printf("Kadu masivu izveidot?\n Ja 5*10 spied 1 \n Ja 4*11 spied 2");
scanf("%d", &choice);
if (choice==1)
r=5&&c=10;
```

The error is on line r=5&&c=10;
How to write it in different way?

Comment: maybe you can tell us what do you expect the code to do

Comment: You may want to read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Whoever down-voted the now-deleted answers appears to have done so inappropriately. From the OP’s comment “How to wire r=5 and c=10” and the text in the source code suggesting that the user is to press 1 for a 5*10 array, it appears the deleted answers gave the desired information (use `{ r = 5; c = 10; }`). I have voted to undelete them.

Comment: I think you may be hung up on the word "and". `&&` is the logical "and" operator, which has a particular mathematical meaning beyond its usual English meaning: it yields a true value if both its operands yield true values, and a false value otherwise. (It also doesn't evaluate the right operand if the left operand is false.) I think what you're looking for is simply to evaluate `r=5` *followed by* evaluating `c=10`. The best way do to this is simply to use two statements enclosed in `{` braces `}`.

Answer (score 6):

```
r=5&&c=10;
```

means  `r = (5&&c) = 10` which is either `0 = 10` or `1 = 10`.

**Explanation:**
The reason for this is precedence of `&&` operator is higher than that of `=` therefore `5` and `c` gets bind to `&&` operator first. After binding this expression looks like

```
r=(5&&c)=10;
```

which is equivalent to either

```
r= 0 =10;
```

or

```
r= 1 =10;
```

The reason behind either expression is that `5 && c` will return either `true` or `false` depending upon the value of `c` (whether it is `0` or not).
As per the comment by OP

> How to wire r=5 and c=10

You can do this as

```
if (choice==1)
{
    r = 5;
    c = 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How to wire r=5 and c=10

Comment: @EinārsOzols Why do you want to do that for can you explain in your question what your goal is?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (choice==1)
{
    r = 5;
    c = 10;
}
```

Except for minor variations in the distribution of whitespace, this is the only way to write it if you're not trying to obfuscate it.

Comment: Well, it is *not* the only way: `if (choice==1)
    r = 5,
    c = 10;`